# 2 Hours transit in Paris Charles de Gaulle (From USA to Spain)

Tags: france, covid-19, paris, cdg

I am a Spaniard expat working in USA.

I have a incoming flight from JFK to AVG (Malaga) with a 2pm stop in CDG.

Its a routine flight that I have done it several times in the past, but not during the pandemic.

From the official site of [De Gaulle](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/flights/covid-19-informations-to-passengers), they are admitting passangers which have all the documents required to go to their final destination (fortunately I have all of them).

Still in its mentioned of the official site of [Embassy of France in Stockhholm](https://se.ambafrance.org/COVID-19-Information-on-measures-upon-arrival-in-France):

```
For your arrival in France, you need to fill in and carry two documents in addition to required travel documents:

   1. An exempted international movement certificate for travel to metropolitan France. You must present this certificate to travel companies before using your travel ticket, as well as to border control authorities (for travel by air, sea and land, including by rail);
   2. A sworn declaration that you do not have COVID-19 symptoms.
```

I understand that from an immigration point of view, I do not enter in France as long as I stay airside, however, the moment I land in France I arrive in France from a legal point of view.

My questions are: Do I need those documents? Furthermore, Do I need any other document to perform my two hours transfer in CDG?

Answer (score 4):

As both France and Spain are in the Schengen Area, you will go through immigration (passport control) in Paris, and will enter France exactly as if it was your final destination.

You may thus be asked for those documents at that time, as well as before boarding.

The documents can be downloaded here: https://mobile.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage (scroll down to “Attestation de déplacement dérogatoire vers la France métropolitaine depuis les pays tiers et déclaration sur l'honneur”, it’s a single file containing both). You should tick the second item in the list as you are an EU national in transit to your country of nationality.

As you are coming from the US you also need a certificate of a negative Covid test taken in the last 72 hours.

Some sources indicate that you also have to undergo a test on arrival, though I have no idea about the details for that, or if that’s in addition to the negative test prior to boarding.

The 2 hour transit may be a bit short if that is the case.

Official info: https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/